# Grails plugin mismatch between pdf0.6 and jasper

Tags: grails

We are working on grails 1.3.7 project. renderpdf0.6 plugin individually working fine. but now, we have added jasper plugin to our project. the jasper related pdf generation is working fine but the renderpdf0.6 plugin is not working **after** adding the jasper plugin. the exception is

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)`

we have been searching for this issue in google and other grails fourms. and some suggested that the core-renderer.jar may be effected by the differenent versions of iText.

Edit:

How to specify in grails, to force the core-renderer plugin to use the specific iText version ?

Comment: Normally in such scenarios, we find out the conflicting dependency and `exclude` or set not to get `transitive` dependencies from the artifact where we do not need it. Have a look at this [information](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a duplicated question. Have you tried the solution in [Which version of iText to use so that both JasperReports and Grails Rendering plugin works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579401/which-version-of-itext-to-use-so-that-both-jasperreports-and-grails-rendering-pl)